# this.value.toFixed is not a function

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have 2 variables:

```
  public value: number = 3.64;
  public rating: number;
```

I'm trying to do the next thing:

```
this.rating = parseFloat(this.value.toFixed(1))
```

But I got the errors:

> this.value.toFixed is not a function

What I did wrong? `value` is exist, and this is a number, I do not understand what is wrong.

Comment: Why are using `this.value` instead of `parseFloat(value.toFixed(1))`?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the code you posted. The error is elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the problem was how I passed `value` in the component.

I'm using the Angular, so I passed value in component like this:

```
<my-component value="3.64"></my-component>
```

So value became a string and not a number. To fix this I changed my template to this:

```
<my-component [value]="3.64"></my-component>
```